# Will new power supply damage current system

Tags: power-supply

I am in the process of buying a 460 Watt PSU (Cooler Master eXtreme Power Plus RS-460-PCAR) to upgrade my computer and be able to run a stronger graphics card. The specs of the PSU is somewhat different from my current PSU and I am scared that it might damage some of the components.

I am running a Dell Optiplex GX270 Pentium 4, 2400 Mhz, 3072 MB (DDR SDRAM) with a standard dell factory PSU.

Please see the difference and tell me whether or not this will be suitable. I have taken this down from my current PSU and as stated by the following website [link](http://www.coolermaster.com/product.php?product_id=3686)

Specs:

### AC Input:

Current/Old:

100 ~ 127V~/ 6A 
200 ~ 240V~/ 3A 
50~60Hz

New:

115V/230V; 10A/6A; 60/50Hz

### DC Output:

Current/ Old:

- +3.3V : 18A (Max Output: 150W)
- +5V : 22A (Max Output: 150W)
- +12V : 14A
- -12V : 1A
- +5Vfp : 2A
- MAX OUTPUT POWER 250W

New:

- +3.3V : 22A (Max Output: 165W)
- +5V : 25A (Max Output: 165W)
- +12V1 : 18A (Max Output: 312W)
- +12V2 : 18A (Max Output: 312W)
- -12V : 0.5A (Max Output: 6W)
- +5Vsb : 2.5A (Max Output: 12.5W)

Please assist me in buying the correct PSU. Will this new one damage my current components?

Comment: Avoid `Cooler Master eXtreme Power Plus RS-460-PCAR` - it has a high failure rate.

Comment: @Sathya - Any links to show high rate of failure?

Comment: @Sathya - What PSU will you recommend? See here:
http://www.sybaritic.co.za/store/index.php?cPath=73_269

Comment: @Abrian: I don't have any particular links, but the Extreme series are budget versions ( contrary to their name) and I suggested against using it because you mentioned `be able to run a stronger graphics card`. My suggestion: http://www.sybaritic.co.za/store/product_info.php?cPath=73_269&products_id=14867 remember: Quality & efficiency is better than quantity
If the vx450 is out of budget, have a look at http://www.sybaritic.co.za/store/product_info.php?cPath=73_269&products_id=17794

Comment: @Sathya - Or here: http://www.pcpower.com/products/description/Silencer_500_Dell/index.html

Comment: @Sathya - Only problem is the dell casing unfortunately does not allow me to use any psu. See here: http://www.computerclearances.co.uk/pub/files/New%20Folder1/1277820458_gx270t.jpg

That is why I think I should try and go for the Silencer 500 Dell?
I can currently get a refurbished model for $69.99 USD.

Any other recommendations?

Comment: Unless I mod the case?

Comment: Graphics card going to be used:

SAPPHIRE HD 4650 1GB DDR2 AGP

http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/?leg=&psn=000101&pid=275

Comment: @Sathya - Any comments/ ideas?

Comment: @Abrian Let me try to find some reviews on the PSU. Though the Silencer says 80+ bronze, I was not able to find details on 80plus' web page. Will check and let you know

Comment: @Sathya - How do you feel about the Consair VX550?

Comment: @Abrian: If you can get a VX550, nothing quite like it, its pretty good

Comment: @Sathya - I spoke to dell and they advised me to NOT use any other power supply than the old one currently being used. They say they cannot confirm that this will work and it might damage the system. I tried to explain to the consultant that the machine will only draw the power that it needs?

Comment: The Corsair VX550W specs:
AC Input Rating: 90 - 264VAC
DC Output: 
+3.3V : (Max Load 30A : 140 W)
+5V : (Max Load 28A : 140 W)
+12V : (Max Load 41A : 492W)
-12V : (Max Load 0.8A : 9.6W)
+5VSB : (Max Load 3A : 15W)

Comment: I contacted Corsair and they said I need to find out the ATX specification of the current PSU/ machine. The 550 supports the latest ATX12V v2.2 standard and is backwards compatible with ATX12V 2.01 systems. I asked Dell what ATX version and they could not tell me. Can you help? I am now very unsure of what to do! Dell says I must forget the HD 4650 and go for something that does not require so much power?!

Comment: @Abrian I think the consultant might be misguided / unaware. Or trying to imrpove upon his sales quota.  At the end of the the a PSU delivers power to the remaining components. It is not possible to damage a system, unless you use a substandard PSU - which the vx550 is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All these power/amperage ratings are *maximums*, your system will only draw the current it needs.

Think about the normal mains electricity from a wall plug. Here in the UK it is normally 230V / 13A (effectively). A 13A kettle will draw 13A, while a 50mA phone charger will just draw 50mA - no risk on damage. The principle is the same here.

So no, higher maximum amperage output will not cause damage.

---

If you are going to also upgrade your machine make sure the new PSU has a maximum output above that of your new set of components, because too little power will cause you problems (crashing / restarts / PSU blow-out ).

Comment: 13A kettle and 3A phone charger? Ahem, that's far from real. I'd say 2A and 200mA. (Yes, it is not important for example, but posting obviously wrong data is... uh... not very good.)

Comment: @white erm, a [3000W kettle](http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/4233093/c_1/1%7Ccategory_root%7CKitchen+and+laundry%7C14418476/c_2/3%7Ccat_15701302%7CKettles%7C14418611.htm) at 230V = 13A, so it's spot on! And 200mA?! How slowly do your phones charge? Remember USB provides 500mA! (PS: that kettle is a random search item, just to prove 3kW kettles exist ;) (PS2: I did make up the phone charger amperage, but 3A is probably a bit high...)

Comment: Tell you what, found a 2A device charger [here](http://www.amazon.com/Griffin-Technology-PowerJolt-Charger-iPhone/dp/B003GAAQXM). 3A is probably still a bit high, but not *insanely* inaccurate...

Comment: Ok, I was partially wrong: the kettle is ok (my fault), but phone is absolutely right: e.g. if charger can provide 3A to *phone*, that would be 3A*5V=15W, and 15W/230V=65mA (I assume that charger is 100% effective), so 3A was a great overestimation.

Comment: @white ah ha! That's it, I'm thinking about the wrong side of the transformer for phone chargers. Doh!

Comment: @DMA: there are no transformer in phone chargers [made in last 5 years]! they're all invertors, i.e. switch-mode supplies, and only have a large inductor inside (apart from semiconductors).

Comment: @white, you know, it's not my day with electronics it seems... oh well

Answer (score 2):

The power output numbers are good, higher maximum power numbers are never a problem.  The only thing I'm concerned about is that I know in the past Dell used power supplies that looked like ATX at a casual glance but which had different pinouts in the plugs that would result in fried components if used.  I don't know when Dell stopped doing that.

Fortunately all the wiring is color coded.  You can check if your Dell uses a standard PSU by comparing the colors of the wires with those in a standard layout.  The clip is on the side with pins 13-24.

http://pinouts.ru/Power/atx_v2_pinout.shtml

The 20 pin layout is here:

http://pinouts.ru/Power/atxpower_pinout.shtml

If you have a 20 pin motherboard you'll need to make sure your PSU has a 20+4 connector that lets you snap the +4 section of the cable off leaving a 20pin section free to plug into the mobo.

Comment: Dan, please have a look at my connector and tell me what you think:
http://tiny.cc/g9sad

It is a 20 pin power supply connector.

Comment: Motherboard Name: Dell OptiPlex GX270; 
Motherboard Chipset: Intel Springdale-G i865G; 
BIOS Type: Phoenix (06/26/06)

Comment: I can't do so now.  your image host is blocked at work.  I added a link to the 20 pin connector layout.

Comment: The link you posted is spot on with my 20 pin connector. :-)

Comment: Then you should be good to go with the new power supply.